# Nested Array Json to Flat Json Format - Help in JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex Nested Array JSON Input to a flat JSON format.
please find the Input, Jolt Transformation & output detail is given below.

**Input** :

Comment: Welcome to SO. The spec is recent and familiar one, but I can't understend what `BE`, which doesn't exist in the input, has got to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Actually BE is also a one more field in Reference Country which is missed some how while formatting.
For Ex.
  "ReferenceCountry": [
    {
      "RefCountry": "DE",
     "Country": "DE",
      "Country": "BE",
      "Country": "NL"
    }
  ]

Comment: Hi. Can you please edit the question question with the related details rather than commenting.

Comment: When I tried to save after added the missed code, I'm getting the below error - 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: You can use the delimiter ````json in the beginning, and  ``` in the end. Aside from that the current input is not a valid JSON(the number of backticks should be three for both)